# Can I combine present perfect tense with past perfect tense?

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-constructions

For example:

> I have gotten a bad stomach because I had eaten a wrong food earlier.

Is that sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct.

The perfect designates a state at the time you are speaking about (your 'Reference Time') which arises out of a prior eventuality: an event or state which occurred at some time *before* Reference Time.

So the present perfect is a *present* tense: its Reference Time is the present and it designates a present state which arises out of a past eventuality.

The past perfect is a *past* tense: its Reference Time is some point in the past and it designates a state at that time which arose out of some event *before* that time.

In your sentence, your main clause employs the present perfect; it is a statement about your present state: the stomach-ache which you have now. It establishes a present Reference Time, and the time of the eventuality in the subordinate clause must be expressed relative to the present—ordinarily, with a simple past:

> ... because I **ate** bad food.

But a present perfect is also acceptable in the subordinate clause:

> ... because I'**ve eaten** bad food.

I've deleted "earlier" because we ordinarily use "earlier" in the same way as a past perfect: to refer to an eventuality *before* a *past* Reference Time. With a present Reference Time it is superfluous to speak of an eventuality cast in the past tense as "earlier": the notion of 'earlier than now' is built in to the past tense.

Note, too, that we do not speak of *a food*—*food* is a non-count noun; we do not usually speak of *wrong food* but of *bad* (or *spoiled*) *food*.

Moreover, it is unlikely that anyone would say "I have gotten" a stomach-ache; we ordinarily say "I have" or, more colloquially, "I've got" a stomach-ache. And in speaking of the cause of a disease or disorder we're more likely to use a *from*+gerund preposition phrase than a *because* clause

> I've got a stomach-ache from eating bad food.